# Is there a way of not hard coding sql queries in my express app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

So I am making an express app for a project and I am using mysql as the db, I had previously hard coded my sql queries in my code, but it is bad practice to do so according to my teacher, so I was looking for a way in which I don't have to hard code.

I have tried queries like find and findAll using mongoose, I am looking for something similar.

```
app.get("/shops/:id",function(req,res){
    var id = req.params.id;

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `menuItems` WHERE shop_id =?',[id],function(error,results,fields) {
        console.log(results);
        res.json(JSON.stringify(results));
    })
});
```

I don't want to hard code my queries as I have in the above code snippet.

Kindly help me get a way for not hard coding sql queries in my app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: While Stored Procedures and ORM are mechanisms to avoid SQL in code, the 'bad practice' statement by 'teachers' (and Stack Overflow answers) should include some justification/tradeoff discussions because Stack overflow is full of people struggling with these alternatives when simple SQL injection free code like the question is perfectly suitable.

Comment: He said, what if I have to change my db, or am the only person who know's sql, and am unavailable.

Comment: Glad you got an explanation. What if your the only one who knows Stored Procedures/ORM, and are unavailable? Maybe ORM knowledge is greater although there seems to be as many ORMs as DBs. Changing DB is some justification for using ORM if the codebase hasn't felt the need to commit to the DB technology. Stored procedures - difficult to debug, and puts code outside of the version control/revision history you'd have in development.

Answer (score -2):

> Stored procedures. Prevents all sorts of possible issues with
> injection, maintenance. Put database code where database code belongs.
>
> ORM tool (like Hibernate, Subsonic, etc.) means you never see a line
> of (*)SQL in the first place. Steeper learning curve, but a great
> practice to start sooner rather than later.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655005/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-avoid-hard-coded-sql-statements) answer.

(*) excerpt modified to match the OPs scenario

Comment: Stored procedures solve *some* forms of injection, and can hide other forms, and generally increase maintenance because they are hard to debug. There's no justification as to why it should be in a database, just a religious looking statement.  Question is about MySQL, not T-SQL, so copying answers isn't that great an idea.

Comment: The question is about general hard coding of sql queries. OP can get the idea from the excerpt though there is a "T-" in front of the "SQL" in the answer. Answer edited however.